# How can i show only local address and PID in powershell?

Tags: powershell, netstat

```
 (netstat -ano) -replace '0\.0\.0\.0:(\d+)','$1        '
```

> what i want is to show only local address and pid using above code

```
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    135                    0                      LISTENING       1172
  TCP    445                    0                      LISTENING       4
  TCP    5040                   0                      LISTENING       7300
  TCP    5357                   0                      LISTENING       4
  TCP    7680                   0                      LISTENING       14100
  TCP    49664                  0                      LISTENING       988
  TCP    49665                  0                      LISTENING       896
  TCP    49666                  0                      LISTENING       1724
  TCP    49667                  0                      LISTENING       1472
  TCP    49668                  0                      LISTENING       3520
  TCP    49728                  0                      LISTENING       968
```

> but what i want

```
Local Address             PID
135                       1172
445                       4
5040                      7300
.                         .
.                         .
.                         .
```

Comment: Why not use `Get-NetTCPConnection`?

Comment: Because I don't know and how do I know about 127 192 and udp

Comment: I left you a comment on your last question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To just get the output you're requesting by column headers in Powershell, you can use:

```
Get-NetTCPConnection | 
  Select-Object LocalAddress, OwningProcess | 
  Sort-Object LocalAddress, OwningProcess
```

Your example data seems to show ports rather than addresses, so:

```
Get-NetTCPConnection | 
  Select-Object LocalPort, OwningProcess | 
  Sort-Object LocalPort, OwningProcess
```

If you also need UDP connections, substitute `Get-NetUDPEndpoint` for `Get-NetTCPConnection` above.

Finally, if you want it all together:

```
(Get-NetUDPEndpoint |
    Select-Object @{L="Proto"; E={"TCP"}}, LocalAddress, LocalPort, OwningProcess
) + (Get-NetTCPConnection |
    Select-Object @{L="Proto"; E={"UDP"}}, LocalAddress, LocalPort, OwningProcess
) |
    Sort-Object Proto, LocalPort, LocalAddress
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got the information you need, now just trim out the excess properties with a nasty regex loop? may need some spacing adjustments

```
 (netstat -ano) `
  -replace '0\.0\.0\.0:(\d+)','$1        '|
  foreach{
    Write-host `
     -nonewline "$([regex]::split("$_",'\s\s+')[2,5])`r`n"
  }
```

I've used grave-accent (poweshell escape-key) to escape linebreaks for readability `|` will pipe to whatever comes on the next line

Comment: Nice regex solution.

Answer (score 0):

Will this do what you want? I assume by "Local Address" you mean port number, and by "PID" you mean the owning process ID. I would not want to rename them if I could avoid it.

```
Get-NetTCPConnection |
    Where-Object { $_.LocalAddress -notmatch '^(127\..*|192\..*|0\..*|::$)' } |
    Select-Object -Property @{n='LocalAddress';e={$_.LocalPort}},@{n='PID';e={$_.OwningProcess}} |
    Sort-Object -Property LocalAddress
```

Comment: You probably meant `-match`.

Comment: I thought the OP wanted to remove those addresses from the output. If not, then yes, it should be `-match` instead of `-notmatch`.

Comment: He just wants to not see (but not filter) the local IP addresses and see which ports are listening on his host.